# The relation between JIT of JVM and GCC (or other existing native compiler)

Tags: gcc, jvm, jit

Does JIT uses GCC or any other native compiler as its backend to generate its native code?

Also, is there any relation between the `C2, C1` of `JIT` and `O1, O2, O3` optimization flags of GCC?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Depends on the particular JVM implementation. E.g. JIT compiler of [Azul Platform Prime](https://www.azul.com/products/prime/) is based on [LLVM](https://llvm.org/); GraalVM JIT is based on [Graal Compiler](https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/reference-manual/java/compiler/). C1 and C2 are distinct compilers written specifically for HotSpot JVM. None of the JVM JIT compilers I'm aware of relate to GCC.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is a standalone operating system process that interprets byte codes (in Java, .class type files) and runs them.  That may mean it runs code that stays entirely inside of the JVM (perhaps string concatenation for example) or calls the underlying O/S to take care of the code it is running (for example, reading a file).  Each JVM will implement this it's own way but it does not create a file in another programming language to then be handled by that environment.

GCC converts C and C++ code to the assembly / machine code appropriate for the processor it is built for (i.e. x86_64, Arm64, etc.)  Generally the output from GCC is meant for a single type of processor and operating system.  There are exceptions - some compilers can build "fat" binaries that contain code targeted at multiple processors.

So, because of that, the JVM doesn't understand or care about the GCC optimization flags.  While the JVM itself is likely compiled with a compiler like GCC once it's built it no longer has any interaction with the GCC (or other) compiler.